# want to show all the images in a gridView in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Location>
   <attraction>
      <ID>291</ID>
      <Title>Great Eastern Hotel</Title>
      <FeaturedImage>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/Lighthouse.jpg</FeaturedImage>
      <FeaturedImage1>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/Banff-National-Park.jpg</FeaturedImage1>
      <FeaturedImage2>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/Banff-National-Park.jpg</FeaturedImage2>
      <FeaturedImage3>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/Banff-National-Park.jpg</FeaturedImage3>
   </attraction>
   <attraction>
      <ID>294</ID>
      <Title>Benaki Museum</Title>
      <FeaturedImage>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/kali.jpg</FeaturedImage>
      <FeaturedImage1>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/Banff-National-Park.jpg</FeaturedImage1>
      <FeaturedImage2>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/09/Jellyfish.jpg</FeaturedImage2>
      <FeaturedImage3>http://tripatlas.s3.amazonaws.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2014/08/Banff-National-Park.jpg</FeaturedImage3>
   </attraction>
</Location>
```

above is the my XML.I want to show all the images after xml parsing.when I open Great Eastern Hotel it shows all images from tag FeaturedImage,1,2 and3.similarly hapens for Benaki Museum.

```
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "attraction"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
    static final String KEY_TITLE= "Title";

    static final String KEY_IMAGE = "FeaturedImage";
    static final String KEY_IMAGE1 = "FeaturedImage1";
    static final String KEY_IMAGE2 = "FeaturedImage2";
    static final String KEY_IMAGE3 = "FeaturedImage3";





    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String xml = ParseXMLMethods8.getXML();
    Document doc = ParseXMLMethods8.XMLfromString(xml);
    int numResults = ParseXMLMethods8.numResults(doc);
    NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

                   for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) 
                   {                            
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            Element e = (Element)children.item(i);
            map.put("ID", ParseXMLMethods8.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put("Title", ParseXMLMethods8.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put("FeaturedImage", ParseXMLMethods8.getValue(e, KEY_IMAGE));
                            map.put("FeaturedImage1", ParseXMLMethods8.getValue(e, KEY_IMAGE1));
                            map.put("FeaturedImage2", ParseXMLMethods8.getValue(e, KEY_IMAGE2));
                            map.put("FeaturedImage3", ParseXMLMethods8.getValue(e, KEY_IMAGE3));

                            mylist.add(map);            
        }
```

above I write my code for getting data from XML parsing.my main purpose is whenever click on an title want to show all images under this title in a gridView.only able to see one image under specific item not get all the images in a gridView.

Comment: Have you any code for this issue?

Comment: be specific about the problem. What have you tried? what is the problem you faced? any thing you tried but failed etc etc..

Comment: I think both of you understand my problem